# Probability of corners and the postage stamp patterns is bingo game.

Tags: probability, combinations, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, pattern-matching

I am very new to this bingo game and want to know how to calculate probability of a particular pattern in bingo game.
Here each column has number  in range of 1-15, 16-30, 31-45, 46-60 ,and 61-75.
Same goes for ball calls which is a randomized pool of 40 balls.
Kindly guide me on this .

Comment: Many things,  but I am not sure if it is fine or not , still working and need an explanation and answer for same. Kindly help.

Comment: if my bingo has no free space , i.e , 25 balls can be called . i am using this :-  p(corner=4 balls match) = C(25,4) * C(50 , 36) / C(75, 40 ) . 40 balls have been selected randomly from a pool of 75 balls.

Comment: Problem 1:  Calculate the probability of achieving the Corners and the Postage Stamp patterns in 1 to 40 ball calls. In other words, for each number, N between 1 and 40, of balls called, what is the probability of having each pattern completed in less than or equal to N balls called?

Problem 2:  Assume that completing the Corners pattern in 30 ball calls pays 5X bet, and completing the Postage Stamp pattern in 35 balls called pays 20X bet. What percentage of the player's bet is returned on average?

Comment: Problem 3:  Assuming the patterns and numbers of balls called are the same as in Problem 2, but we want to return very close to 92 percent of the player's bet on average. What integer multiples of the player's bet should each pattern and ball count combination pay?